# ¿Como cambio adapto el tamaño de un boton al GridPane?

Tags: imagen, javafx, botón

Estoy tratando de acomodar un boton en un GridPane de 8x8 que mide 200px ya intente con en el boton *setMaxSize* y *setPrefSize* pero me sigue apareciendo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

parece que el problema es que aparece un tipo de borde en la imagen pero no se como corregirlo
el codigo con el que genero esto es este

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        campos[i][j]=new Campo(new Coordenadas(i, j));
        ImageView aux=new ImageView(alzado);
        campos[i][j].setGraphic(aux);
        aux.setFitHeight(25);
        aux.setFitWidth(25);
        grpCampo.setMaxSize(200, 200);
        grpCampo.add(campos[i][j], i, j);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema está siendo el estilo por defecto que tiene el botón de javafx, concretamente el padding.

Prueba a hacer lo siguiente:

```
campo.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0; -fx-border-width: 0; -fx-background-color: transparent;");
```

El padding también lo puedes asignar directamente por código:

```
campo.setPadding(new Insets(0D, 0D, 0D, 10D));
```

De todos modos, para aclarar perfectamente a tu pregunta (yo simplemente lo intuí) deberías indicar de que clase extiende Campo.

Un saludo y espero que te funcione.